# Pacman(Arch linux) on LFS

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, lfs

Is it possible to have a `package manager`(in my case `pacman`) on `LFS`?
Not just compiling it will it work?

Comment: Pacman is distro-agnostic: there is no reason why it shouldn't work on LFS...

Comment: Hell it runs on Windows via msys2

Answer (score 0):

Once you install a package manager and begin to use it (plus repos), lfs basically ceases to be lfs and becomes the distro using that package manager and repos. What here is your goal in using lfs? If you want special self-built packages/kernel, you may as well install arch linux and then build those packages with makepkg and/or write your own PKGBUILD for those packages not in the default repos.

Comment: Hmm, yeah it's kinda pointless. Anyway thanks for reply.

Comment: Not pointless if you start building your own repo collection and use the system to get your own PKGBUILD files. check https://github.com/benvd/lfs-pacman or https://github.com/djlucas/LFS-Pacman